# DropDownList item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I'm writing an asp.Net MVC application and i have a problem. I need two controls - one is DropDownList and the other is Button.

Razor/Html:

```
<h3 class="text-center margin">Parking Spaces in <strong>@Model.Company.Name</strong></h3>

@Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.UnassignedParkingSpaces, new SelectList(Model.UnassignedParkingSpaces, "Id", "Id"), new { @class = "form-control" })
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm button-width" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Assign", "Company", new {buildingGuid = Model.BuildingGuid, companyGuid = Model.Company.Guid, parkingSpaceGuid =  })'">
<i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> @ResourcesGeneral.AssignButton
</a>
```

CompanyController:

```
public ActionResult Assign(Guid parkingSpaceGuid, Guid companyGuid, Guid buildingGuid)
    {
        var building = _buildingReader.GetBuilding(buildingGuid);
        building.AssignParkingSpace(parkingSpaceGuid, companyGuid);

        return RedirectToAction("DisplayParkingSpaces", new { buildingGuid, companyGuid});
    }
```

My ViewController that i use in Html:

```
public class CompanyParkingSpacesViewModel
{
    public Guid BuildingGuid { get; set; }
    public AllParkingSpacesListViewModel AllParkingSpacesListViewModel { get; set ; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public List<ParkingSpace> CompanyParkingSpaces { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ParkingSpace> UnassignedParkingSpaces { get; set; }
}
```

And ParkingSpace Model:

```
public class ParkingSpace
{
    public Guid Guid { get;}
    public string DescriptionHint { get; private set; }
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    private ParkingSpaceState State { get; set; }
}
```

So i need to pass to my button element that i've selected in DropDownList somy controller have all parameters. How can you do it?

Comment: Yes, parkingSpaceGuid =  , is empty because i need help with filling that field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your input control(SELECT element) in a form and submit the form.

You are also using the DropDownListFor method incorrect. For showing the dropdown, you do not need to use the `ParkingSpace` entity collection as the type. You can simply use the `List<SelectListItem>` type. Also you need to add another property for the selected option value.

```
public class CompanyParkingSpacesViewModel
{
    public Guid BuildingGuid { get; set; }
    public AllParkingSpacesListViewModel AllParkingSpacesListViewModel { get; set ; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public List<ParkingSpace> CompanyParkingSpaces { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UnassignedParkingSpaces { get; set; }
    public Guid SelectedParkingSpace { set;get;}
}
```

Make sure you are loading the data in your GET action

```
public ActionResult Assign()
{
  var  vm = new CompanyParkingSpacesViewModel();
  vm.UnassignedParkingSpace = db.ParkingSpaces
                               .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value = x.Guid.ToString(), 
                                                         Text=x.DescriptionHint }).ToList();
  //Assign other properties as well
  vm.Company=new Company();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your form.

```
@model CompanyParkingSpacesViewModel
@using(Hml.BginForm("Assign","YourControllerName"))
{
   <label>Select a parking space </label>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.SelectedParkingSpace, 
           Model.UnassignedParkingSpace,new { @class = "form-control" })
  <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
}
```

Make sure your action method parameter name matches with the SELECT element name attribute value.

```
public ActionResult Assign(Guid SelectedParkingSpace, Guid companyGuid, 
                                                                          Guid buildingGuid)
{
    var building = _buildingReader.GetBuilding(buildingGuid);
    building.AssignParkingSpace(SelectedParkingSpace, companyGuid);
    return RedirectToAction("DisplayParkingSpaces", new { buildingGuid, companyGuid});
}
```

Since your `Assign` action method code is expecting `buildingGuid` and `companyGuid`, you need to keep those also in the form so that it will be mapped to the method parameters when the form is submitted. You can keep this in hidden input fields.

```
@using(Hml.BginForm("Assign","YourControllerName")
{
   <label>Select a parking space </label>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.SelectedParkingSpace, 
           Model.UnassignedParkingSpace,new { @class = "form-control" })

  <input type="hidden" name="companyGuid" value="@Model.Company.Guid" />
  <input type="hidden" name="buildingGuid" value="@Model.BuildingGuid" />
  <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
}
```

Comment: Edited and showed whole structure, sorry for ealier ;P

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'UnassignedParkingSpaces' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Assign(System.Guid, System.Guid, System.Guid)' in 'Web.Controllers.CompanyController' - That type of error ;p

Comment: Does the `Id` property value of items in `Model.UnassignedParkingSpaces` of type Guid ? The answer assumes it is. Can you check the view source of the page and see the value of each options ?Is it a Guid ?

Comment: Thats why i showed the structure of the ParkingSpace Model. Im showing an int in the dropdown coz Guids dont mean anything, and i need to send other field from the Model -> Guid Guid

Comment: Does your `building.AssignParkingSpace` accept an int param or Guid param for the first param ?

Comment: right now its AssignParkingSpace(Guid parkingSpaceGuid, Guid companyGuid)

Comment: You are using the helper method wrong. See the updated answer.

Comment: There are 3 problems with your solution.
1. The Action Assign dont have its own View coz its only onClick Post Action.
2. I don't have DataBase in my solution coz i'm doin it with DDD and i don't need one right now so i only have methods "GetUnassignedParkingSpaces" or "GetAllParkingSpaces"
3. In your case i will have a DropDown with Guids but i wanna have Id's in the DropDown but i wanna pass Guid to the method.

Comment: Your assign method is doing a redirect. So there is no need of a view. You cannot render a dropdown with Id and send the Guid when form is submitted. I suggest you read about the basics of MVC before proceeding any further.